# When clicking link, link needs to be replaced with content

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have 2 div's, the first is just a link,

```
 <div id="click1" class="grid-66 mobile-grid-100 user-photo-tag-click" style="display:block" onclick="replace()"> <a href="#">CLICK AND SHOW TAGS</a>

        </div>
```

The second is a list of photo tags,

```
<div id="click2" class="grid-66 mobile-grid-100 user-photo-tag" style="display:none">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">RACE SHOP</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">AAA</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">77</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I am trying to set it up so that when the link is clicked, it disappears and the photo tags show in its place. I have started a JSFIDDLE here, https://jsfiddle.net/patricksharer/g43t1bnh/ so that my code can be viewed cleanly. My javascript function doesnt seem to be working. Can somone please take a look and tell me why? Thanks

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g43t1bnh/1/)? In your fiddle setting, that `replace` is declared in `window.onload` handler, so it can't be access by your div's onclick handler, change the settings to No wrap - in <body> should work.

Comment: @fuyushimoya You rock! Can you tell me how this would be effected or how it should change on a live site? Is this something to do with JSFiddle or no?

Comment: Where and how do you declare that function in your live site?

Comment: Ah I get you now. Its placed before the closing body tag. So if I place this in an external js file and reference it in the head will anything have to change?

Comment: It should be ok. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CtgpDP9H6eKhtZKeAeBf?p=preview).